# Whats means the : operator in str.format()?

Tags: python-2.7, formatting

Take `{:.2f}.format(x)` for example. This gives me the as output a fixed-point number with precision 2 as output. What does the `:` means?
I also have another question:
Why does the upper function doesn't work when i give as input `x = 7.5643915285818e+210+4.6951592215e+280j`?

Answer (score 0):

Colon (:) is used instead of % in formatting.

Refer this [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples)